# Could not connect to development server

Tags: react-native

Version Details :

```
 react-native : 0.21.0   
 npm: '3.3.6',   
 node: '5.0.0'
 watchman : 4.4.0
```

When i tried to run my app in iOS simulator , transform is hanging ..

`[2:53:33 PM] <START> transform
transforming [========================================] 100% 508/509`

and i am seeing red error screen in simulator with message `Could not connect to development server..`

**Edit:**

```
    [5:15:30 PM] transforming [=======] 100% 507/509transforming:  /projects/mobile-examples/index.ios.js
    transforming [========================================] 100% 508/509
    transforming [========================================] 100% 509/509
    [5:35:42 PM] <END>   transform (1402427ms)
    it took 20 min to transform
```

looks like transform issue , any idea why its taking so much time ?

**Edit2:**

Downgraded my node and npm to 4.0.0 and 2.x , transformer is alot faster now :)

Comment: Just a guess, but this might be an issue with **watchman**. Try to re-install or update it with brew.

Comment: i already have latest version. >  brew upgrade watchman
Error: watchman HEAD already installed

Comment: Just Refresh the app by Cmd+R

Comment: Try debugging where it hangs by setting an env variable:
export DEBUG=ReactNativePackager:*; npm start

Documented here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/packager